# Is a one step derivation grammar context free?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

Suppose we have a grammar having a one step derivation like

S -> a

where 'S' is a variable and 'a' is a terminal.

Since this grammar does not pump terminals, can we say that the language generated is context free by using pumping lemma?

Comment: I don't quite get your question… If $S\to a$ is the only rule of the grammar $G$, then $L(G) = \{a\}$ is obviously context-free. If not, then how could we conclude anything on the grammar without more information?

Comment: @Nathaniel i have edited my question to include pumping lemma. I am not understanding how to use pumping lemma to prove this language as a CFL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $S\to a$ is the only rule of a grammar $G$, then $L(G) = \{a\}$ is finite hence context-free.

You cannot use the pumping lemma to prove that the language is context-free for two reasons:

- the conclusion of the pumping lemma is a necessary condition to be context-free, not a sufficient condition. It is often used to prove that languages or grammars are **not** context-free;
- the conclusion of the pumping lemma applies to words with size above a certain threshold (depending on the language). You cannot conclude anything on words below this threshold.

Comment: Thanks for answering